# Give commands to multiple RDP and wait for result

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a repetitive task at the end of the month to give commands to multiple Remote Desktop Connections (Win7, Win Server 2008, Win server 2012, Win 8 ...) and i need to open all of them one by one to do this task. I want somekind of tool that would log on each and every one of them and give commands.

Here is what i tried :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    rdp.Server = "1.2.3.4";
    rdp.UserName = "Rmlabuser2";

    IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
    secured.ClearTextPassword = "Rmlabuser2";
    rdp.Connect();

    // open cmd.exe and give commands like VER and return output into a message text box
    // rdp.SecuredSettings.StartProgram = @"c:\windows\System32\cmd.exe";
}
```

Full code : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

Any ideeas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) to run commands on remote computer.

If you need to run commands within active session, you can create a scheduled task on that computer that will do the needed stuff. Scheduled tasks can be configured to run under currently logged-in session or from system/predefined account.

There are a number of C# libraries that can work with windows scheduled tasks. For example http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: I think you still need to provide a command to psexec, even for interactive mode. Try appending " cmd" to your command line to start the command line interpreter

Comment: don't quite understand, an example please? i even tried `psexec \\1.2.3.4 -u Rmlabuser2 -p Rmlabuser2 -l -d "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"
` got 
Couldn't access 1.2.3.4:
The network path was not found.

Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on 1.2.3.4.

Comment: That should do the thing for interactive command prompt - `psexec \\1.2.3.4 -u Rmlabuser2 -p Rmlabuser2  -i cmd.exe` . Also make sure that windows file sharing is enabled on that computer, that it is allowed through  firewall, and that you are using admin account to connect to that PC.

Comment: i don't want to make any config on 100 servers, just automate as if i log in on each of them trough RDP, and this command still dosen't work ... i would have more confidance in C#, i have managed to connect, press windows key, write cmd, but i cannot press ENTER ...